# topspin interface crash on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, crash, interface

Recently, when using Ubuntu 20.04 to run topspin 3.2, the topspin can start normally. However, when I click the button on the software interface, the software interface will crash and the terminal does not report any errors. At this time, other software of the system is still normal. The previous use of topspin 3.2 was normal. I tried to install and use the latest version of topspin 4.1. I also encountered the same problem. For the problem that only recently occurred, I can basically rule out the problem that is not from the topspin. Recently, the Ubuntu system has been updated normally, and there is no other operation. It hasn't been solved now, does anyone know why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem may be related with java. I have another software. There are both java version and non-java version. The non-java version has no problem. The Java version has similar problem. But I install a new java, the problem remains!

Comment: When I add a new user, the problem is been solved. I don't know why?